# ErrorException in Macroable.php line 74

Tags: php, laravel-5

**THE ERROR MESSAGE**

Method wardrobeimage does not exist. (View: C:\laragon\www\wasamar\resources\views\main_app\admin\wardrobe.blade.php)

I have this issue when i want to call my wardrobe image class to display the wardrobe attire images.

**WARDROBE MODEL**

```
<?php

namespace App\Wasamar;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Wardrobe extends Model
{
/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */

protected $table = 'wardrobes';

public function wardrobeimage(){

    return $this->hasMany('App\Wasamar\Wardrobeimage','wardrobe_id');
}
}
```

**WARDROBE IMAGE CLASS**

```
<?php

namespace App\Wasamar;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Wardrobeimage extends Model
{
/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'wardrobeimages';


function wardrobe(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Wasamar\Wardrobe','id');
}
}
```

So when i do this it prompt the error

```
<?php 
$wardrobeAttires = Wardrobe::where('user_id',$user->id)->get(); 
?>

$wardrobeAttires->wardrobeimage()->where('wardrobe_attire_view',0)->get();
```

Comment: `->get()` returns a collection. You want to do `->first()` which will give you a single Wardrobe model. Then you should be able to call the `wardrobeimage()` method on that model.

Comment: @jszobody based on your suggestion of me using first() instead of get(), it did work but that is not what i want to achieve. i want to be able to loop through the wardrobe image attire and display them.

Comment: Then loop through the collection first. You can't call a model method on the collection directly.

Comment: @jszobody sorry for not commenting quick, The issue still remains the same when i add a get() method.

Answer (score 0):

Relation setup is misleading. Wardrobe hasMany Wardrobe images. It should be wardrobeimages() for naming convention. And if `wardrobe_id` is foreign key, the relation should be:

**Wardrobe Model:**

```
public function wardrobeimages(){

    return $this->hasMany('App\Wasamar\Wardrobeimage','wardrobe_id');
}
```

**Wardrobeimage:**

```
function wardrobe(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Wasamar\Wardrobe','wardrobe_id');
}
```

And in controller:

```
$wardrobeAttires = Wardrobe::with(['wardrobeimage'=>function($query)
                       {
                            $query->where('wardrobe_attire_view',0);
                      }])
                 ->where('user_id',$user->id)->get();
```

This gives the collection of wardrobeAttires:

```
foreach($wardrobeAttires as  $wardrobeAttire)
{
   foreach($wardrobeAttire->wardrobeimages as $wardrobeimage)
   {
             print_r($wardrobeimage);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, but thanks everyone for your support.

```
@foreach( $wardrobeAttires as $wardrobeAttire) 
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="small-4 columns">

                                    <div class="image-wrapper overlay-slide-in-left">

                                        @if( count($wardrobeAttire->wardrobeimages()->where('wardrobe_attire_view',0)->first()) === 0 )
                                            <img src="{{ domain_name() . '/f-assets/img/' . 'wardrobe_attire_default_image.png' }}" alt="Attire image" />
                                        @else
                                            @if( count($wardrobeAttire->wardrobeimages()->where('wardrobe_attire_view',0)->get()) >= 1 )
                                                @foreach($wardrobeAttire->wardrobeimages()->where('wardrobe_attire_view',0)->get() as $wardrobeAttireImage)
                                                    <img src="{{ domain_name().'/ws-uploads/wardrobe-attire-image/thumbnail/'.$wardrobeAttireImage->new_name }}" alt="Attire image" />
                                                @endforeach
                                            @endif
                                        @endif

                                        <div class="image-overlay-content">
                                            <h2>.overlay-slide-in-left</h2>
                                            <p class="price">$2319.99</p>
                                            <a href="#" class="button">Buy Me</a>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        @endforeach
```

Instead of $wardrobeAttires should be $wardrobeAttire inside the @foreach loops, that was the bug.